# htaccess redirect of a directory without causing looping

Tags: .htaccess

Directory "xx" has several directories.

I want that when people visit "domain.com/xx" they are redirected to one of the directories inside "xx", called "zzzzz".

But this should not affect any other directory inside "xx".

However, when I write

```
redirect 301 /xx /xx/zzzzz
```

it causes a loop. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?xx/?$ /xx/zzzzz [R,L]
```

For request URL `domain.com/xx` or `domain.com/xx/`, redirect to `domain.com/xx/zzzzz`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't test your suggestion, but I found this and it solved my problem: **RedirectMatch 301 ^/xx/?$ /xx/zzzzz**

Answer (score 0):

`redirect 301 /xx /xx/zzzzz` will definitely cause an infinite redirect chain because the url pattern and destination path are identical. `/xx` also matches the target path `/xx/zzzz` .

You need  to exclude matching the `/zzzz` segment in your pattern. You can either  use `Redirectmatch`  or `RewriteRule` to solve the issue

```
 Redirectmatch ^/xx((?!/zzzzz).*)$ /xx/zzzz
```

Clear your browser  cache before testing this Redirect.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't test your suggestion, but I found this and it solved my problem: **RedirectMatch 301 ^/xx/?$ /xx/zzzzz**

Answer (score -1):

I found this and it solved my problem:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/xx/?$ /xx/zzzzz
```